# What are the dangers of using query strings?

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery-ui

I'm building a website like gumtree and OLX, a friend of mine told me that it's gonna be easy to hack because it uses query strings to perform most operations.

For example when I search for a car my URL looks like http://www.kasitree.co.nf/?sv=car&township=&catagory=Cars&province=Western+Cape

Where as on gumtree when I search for a car their URL looks like 
https://www.gumtree.co.za/s-automotive-vehicles/stellenbosch/car/v1c5l3100295q0p1

He didn't tell me the dangers of using query strings, he just told me that query strings  make your website vulnerable to hackers.

Any alternative to using query strings?

Comment: false. what might make this vulnerable is if you're passing those parameters unsanitized directly to an SQL query, but that's just as vulnerable using POST method, or any other.

Comment: Hi Jeff , Thanks for your comment :) I feel a bit positive about my site now

Comment: As long as you use parameterized queries, using query-strings are not unsafe. If you're using the $_GET-variables directly in your queries, on the other hand... then you're in for a world of hurt in the future.

Comment: Thank you, comment noted :)

Answer (score 2):

Query strings don't make your site vulnerable to hackers. Query strings are just *ugly* and should be used sparingly, and when they are used you should make an effort to keep them neat and orderly.

A lot of modern web frameworks make query strings less ugly by embedding query parameters in the URL itself. That is `/cars/fiat/30132` is analogous to `/cars?vendor=fiat&id=30132` in legacy CGI parlance.

There is nothing more secure or less secure when using query strings. Exposing parameters in the URL invites tinkering with the options, sure, but anyone who's a "hacker" will know that other components of the URL are also easily tweaked, plus any POST form can have its contents altered by using the built-in development tools in any web browser.

The basic rule in web development is **trust nothing provided by the user**. Anything can and will be manipulated, so you **must** do your own verification on any incoming parameters or data, you **must** properly escape these values when inserting them into other contexts such as HTML,  SQL, or even another URL.

If you want your site to be secure you have to use HTTPS, and you need to be very, very suspicious of all user data. Your friend here is wildly misinformed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer....one question; How do I go about embedding query strings to the URL itself, I want to stick to modern methods of development. You're right I noticed that most sites use this form /cars/fiat/30132 of URLs, In the case of /cars?vendor=fiat&id=30132, I'd have something like $vender = $_GET['vendor']; to grab the vendor from the URL, now how do I grab the vendor when using  /cars/fiat/30132 ?

Comment: Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) with a routing engine does this. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a good example, and here's the [documentation on their routing system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing).